# Cardinal inequality: Show that if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are cardinals and $\beta \leq \gamma$ then $\beta^{\alpha} \leq \gamma^{\alpha}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are cardinals and $\beta \leq \gamma$ then $\beta^{\alpha} \leq \gamma^{\alpha}$.

I got it all confused when I tried constructing an injective function... Can you please show a solution step-by-step to this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you only use the things you are given, there is only one way to stick them together.